# Excel on cell "X" change, insert date now into cell "Y" while not affecting the other cells with same functioanlity

Tags: excel

Is it possible without visual basic to achieve this:
I'm pasting this at cell B1

```
=IF(A1="","Not Allocated",NOW())
```

And then i select both cells A1 and B1 and copy/drag them to where I want.
Then every time I change the value of A1 the B1 value equals the new Time i.e the time when i have changed A1 cell.

But when i have copied this to the other cells when i change A1 all the B1,B2,B3 values changes to the new time. I want them to stay where they were and only affect the corresponding cell. Is this possible without VB

Comment: Instead of using `Now()`, I would link the formula to a cell and enter a time into the cell using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `;`

Comment: how you explain step by step because i don't understand what you mean

Comment: e.g. `=IF(A1="","Not Allocated",C1)`, then you go to cell C1 and press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `;`

Comment: You cannot use a formula like that to create a fixed timestamp: it can always recalculate and update to the current value of NOW()